# How to combine WebDriver find_elements_by* calls while keeping track of the order of results?

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

On a typical Google local search results page such as [this](https://www.google.com/#q=chiropractors%2BDallas,+TX&rflfq=1&rlha=0&tbm=lcl) which has 20 results:

[image]

Reviews are either given as 'No reviews', which can be extracted using:

```
driver.find_elements_by_class_name("_Juh")
```

or:

a non-zero number of reviews, which can be extracted using:

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1)")
```

or:

just a number in brackets e.g. (7), which can be extracted using:

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(3) > span:nth-child(1)")
```

As such, I can extract all 20 review counts. **The challenge:** I need to be able to (i) extract them all in one go and (ii) keep track of their position in the list of 20 results. This is because I will click each result, extract some details from the map pane, and then collate these with the review count, for each result. How best to achieve this?

Comment: have you got your solution yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following- it will grab all serially but with star rating! Then apply python to clean them-

I tried for [this](https://www.google.com.bd/search?q=chiropractors%2BDallas,%20TX&biw=1600&bih=789&noj=1&tbs=lf:1,lf_ui:2&tbm=lcl&ei=km0oVvLaI4XtugSM7JZ4&sa=N&fll=32.954817332283156,-96.80201819999996&fspn=0.25754523132211915,0.81024169921875&fz=11&oll=32.88593891177962,-96.80201819999996&ospn=0.4203501256633899,0.81024169921875&oz=11&ved=0CKkBENAnahUKEwjy68ePptXIAhWFto4KHQy2BQ8&rlfi=hd:;si:#rlfi=hd:;si:) link.

**Xpath**

```
//*[@class='_rl']/following-sibling::span[1]
```

**It returns**

```
4.9(7)
3 reviews
3 reviews
4.2(24)
5.0(44)
4.9(16)
4.9(7)
4.7(5)
2 reviews
No reviews
5.0(14)
4.9(9)
4.7(5)
4.3(5)
1 review
4.6(7)
No reviews
4 reviews
2 reviews
4.7(12)
```

Now apply python to clean (you follow your way - it is just test)-

```
>>> s = '''4.9(7)
3 reviews
3 reviews
4.2(24)
5.0(44)
4.9(16)
4.9(7)
4.7(5)
2 reviews
No reviews
5.0(14)
4.9(9)
4.7(5)
4.3(5)
1 review
4.6(7)
No reviews
4 reviews
2 reviews
4.7(12)'''
>>> mylist=s.split('\n')
>>> clndlist = [i.split("(")[-1].replace(")","") if "(" in i else i for i in mylist]
>>> clndlist

>>> ['7', '3 reviews', '3 reviews', '24', '44', '16', '7', '5', '2 reviews', 'No reviews', '14', '9', '5', '5', '1 review', '7', 'No reviews', '4 reviews', '2 reviews', '12', '']
```

Comment: Beautifully done. I was not familiar with following-sibling. Oddly, I get newlines in my extractions when there are star ratings - see here http://pastebin.com/r43tq9TL. Did you also get newlines but you removed them before pasting in your results above?

Comment: [i.get_attribute('text') for i in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='_rl']/following-sibling::span[1]")]

Comment: Hmmm, that returns a list of `None` values.

Comment: Ah! -tried? `[i.text.replace('\n','') for i in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='_rl']/following-sibling::span[1]")]`  or `strip()`